# Negation of nleftrightarrow?

Tags: amssymb

If I use `$\nleftrightarrow$` from the `amssymb` package, I get a negated double-headed arrow. So far, so good.

Unfortunately, the `$\nleftrightarrow$` seems to have smaller arrow heads then the `$\leftrightarrow$`, which does not look nice if I want to use one symbol for the negation of the other.

What is the non-negated equivalent of the `$\nleftrightarrow$`?

Comment: The `mathabx` don't present this problem, but changes a little these symbols.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use Lua- or XeLaTeX, you may want to use the package `unicode-math` which got this fixed. The default font here is Latin Modern Math as would be standard in 'normal' LaTeX.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$A\leftrightarrow B\nleftrightarrow C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are the possible fonts and the unicode presented in the manual of `unicode-math`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taking the suggestion of skpblack, but limiting the importation to just those two glyphs from `mathabx` (since that package changes many, many glyphs),  we have here denoted those two imported glyphs as `\varleftrightarrow` and `\nvarleftrightarrow`.  All other math glyphs are as defined by `amssymb` or LaTeX, itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% Setup the matha font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)
% to completely replace the \subset character, you can replace
% \varsubset with \subset

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varleftrightarrow}{3}{matha}{"D8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nvarleftrightarrow}{3}{matha}{"DC}
\begin{document}
\texttt{amssymb} left-right arrow and negation
\[
A \leftrightarrow B \nleftrightarrow C
\]

\texttt{mathabx} left-right arrow and negation
\[
A \varleftrightarrow B \nvarleftrightarrow C
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]